# How to Call the Credentials from .secrets File in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, security, credentials

Recently I've made a **twitter-bot** using **tweepy** for my own need. Now to host it online 24x7, I first tried Heroku (couldn't add the credit/debit card), then *pythonanywhere.com* (I don't know why the console was shutting down after a day), then *repl.it* (the API keys were returning **None** from the **.env** file - though in my system it was running fine) and finally **WayScript.com**.

Now, here I encountered a new file type saying **.secrets**. I used **.env** for storing all the keys, but they were asking to save those credentials in the **.secrets** file. They also provide the **.env** file type. But it says that it is preferable to add those credentials in the **.secrets** file as they will be saved as an encrypted string in that case. Here is the screen view -
[image: Screen View]

Now, if I use **.env** file, I can easily import the credentials using the code below -

```
import os
Secret_Key = os.environ['key']
```

**But if I use a *.secret* file, then how the credentials will be called?**

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Regarding the PythonAnywhere bit -- consoles are ephemeral by design on PA, if you need a long running jobs, you need the Always-on task feature:  [https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AlwaysOnTasks/](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AlwaysOnTasks/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use ws.environment to read values stored inside .secrets file. If you need to retrieve your API key you can do that as follow.

```
api_key = ws.environment['API_KEY']
```